# validating id coming back from client php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am using `BIGINT` in mysql server for `id`. There are some operation which needs for client side storage of `id`. So, I can't trust the `id` coming back from the user brower. I want to validate that data. so the question is

1) what is the exact range of `BIGINT(255)`. The range of the `BIGINT(255)` is not easy to validate. please let me know how to validate it with regex.

2) should I  do this check on `id` coming back from client,  am  I just over concerning the issue or should I validate the `id` to avoid sql injection?

Comment: 1) "A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615. "

Comment: 2) no idea what you are asking

Comment: The ranges of all the integer types is at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From MySQL [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html):

For `signed BIGINT`: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

For `unsigned BIGINT`: 0 to 18446744073709551615

2. I think you just need to verify if the `ID` is a number, and within the range defined by `BIGINT`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was thinking..

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to check the returning id against the db ?

Comment: @tuananh : You're confused with `signed/unsigned` with `minimum/maximum`

Comment: @Dagon I guess if the ID is in the incorrect form, you don't even need to query db